# Use an RX observable to create a "debounce" effect

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've got an FTP client that I want to leave connected to the FTP server, unless (say) a minute passes with no activity. I'd like to do this using an Observable.

Here's a very dumbed-down Linqpad script that demonstrates the concept:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var client = new Client();
    client.Connect();

    var debounce = new Subject<int>();
    debounce
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Subscribe(eventNumber => client.Disconnect(eventNumber));

    // Something uses the FTP client
    debounce.OnNext(1);
    await Task.Delay(200);

    // Something else uses the FTP client
    debounce.OnNext(2);
    await Task.Delay(300);

    // No activity, the client will disconnect
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

public class Client
{
    public void Connect() => Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    public void Disconnect(int eventNumber) => Console.WriteLine($"Disconnected: {eventNumber}");
}
```

This works perfectly - the client disconnects after event "2".

**Question**: Is there a better way to do this? Or more accurately, is there a better way to do this without using the `Subject`?

### Edit

Here's a more fleshed-out version of the class - effectively, it is subscribed to an observable which will tell it some files that need to be downloaded; if no files come through for some timeout, then I want the client to disconnect.

```
public class MyClassThatDownloadsViaFtp
{
    private IObserver<Unit> _debouncer;
    private FtpClient _client;

    public MyClassThatDownloadsViaFtp(IObservable<FileToDownload> filesToDownloadViaFtp)
    {
        filesToDownloadViaFtp.Subscribe(DownloadFileViaFtp);

        // Disconnect after a minute of activity
        _debouncer = new Subject<Unit>();
        _debouncer
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
            .Subscribe(_ => DisconnectFtpClient());
    }

    public void DownloadFileViaFtp(FileToDownload file)
    {
        if (_client == null) _client = ConnectFtpClient();

        // Signal that the client is doing some work to prevent disconnect
        _debouncer.OnNext(Unit.Default);
        _client.Download(file.PathOnFtpServer);
    }

    // implementation irrelivent
    private FtpClient ConnectFtpClient() => new FtpClient();
    private FtpClient DisconnectFtpClient() => _client = null;
}
```

I figured out that since I have a source stream, it's probably easier to throttle it to achieve the same effect (as follows); however, I'd still like to know the best way to do this in cases where I do **not** have a source stream that I can throttle.

```
public class MyClassThatDownloadsViaFtp 
{
    private FtpClient _client;

    public MyClassThatDownloadsViaFtp(IObservable<FileToDownload> filesToDownloadViaFtp)
    {
        filesToDownloadViaFtp
            .Select(DownloadFileViaFtp)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
            .Subscribe(_ => DisconnectFtpClient());
    }

    public Unit DownloadFileViaFtp(FileToDownload file)
    {
        if (_client == null) _client = ConnectFtpClient();
        _client.Download(file.PathOnFtpServer);

        return Unit.Default;
    }

    // implementation irrelivent
    private FtpClient ConnectFtpClient() => new FtpClient();
    private FtpClient DisconnectFtpClient() => _client = null; 
}
```

Comment: What does activity look like on the client? You need some sort of event (in the place of the subject) to cause the client to remain alive. It's fairly easy to do what you want with the `Observable.Amb` operator, but I need to know want to use to trigger the extended lease.

Comment: I've added more examples showing a better example of what I'm trying to achieve, hopefully that helps. What the client is doing is irrelivent in this case (I think!) -- it more comes down to how much it's being used. I'm new to observables so I could be way off base here!

Comment: The client needs to signal that it is still active. So it's not irrelevant.

Comment: Also, what is this `FtpClient`? Is it the same as `Client`? And why is `_client = null` the way to disconnect the client? This doesn't seem like real code.

Comment: You're right, it's not real code, it's an abstraction of real code though. The client is active if it has something to download (via the `filesToDownloadViaFtp` observable). The downloads will be very fast (< 1 second), and the timeout to disconnect is set to 1 minute, so the client itself shouldn't need to signal that it's still active. If nothing has come in to the download queue for 1 minute, it's safe to assume the client is no longer active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically answered your question with this:

```
public MyClassThatDownloadsViaFtp(IObservable<FileToDownload> filesToDownloadViaFtp)
{
    filesToDownloadViaFtp
        .Select(DownloadFileViaFtp)
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
        .Subscribe(_ => DisconnectFtpClient());
}
```

If you don't have a convenient stream like `filesToDownloadViaFtp` then create one from either `Observable.Create` or `Observable.FromEvent`, or `Observable.FromEventPattern`, etc..

One quibble: `Select` is ideally run with no side-effects and `DownloadFileViaFtp` is very much a side-effect. Side-effects are best in a `Subscribe` call.

Comment: Hmm, fair point, I should probably subscribe twice (once for downloading, once for throttling).... thanks for the tip!